# ASP.NET Core Dockerfile default template: "COPY *.sln ./" No source files were specified

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I've created a standard ASP.NET core web app using the Visual Studio default template and added Docker support. This creates the following file/folder structure

```
+ Test01
    +Test01
        -All project files
        -Dockerfile
    -Test01.sln
    -docker-compose.xxx files
    -.dockerignore
```

The Dockerfile is created by VS as follows:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY Test01/Test01.csproj Test01/
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Test01
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Test01.dll"]
```

Now when I use the Docker CLI to build the image based on the Dockerfile which in the **project folder**:

```
cd -to project folder-
docker build -t test01 .
```

I get the following error:

```
Step 6/17 : COPY *.sln ./
No source files were specified
```

Obviously this happens because the Dockerfile is in the project folder (/Test01/Test01), while the .sln file is in the parent folder (/Test01).

I don't understand however why the default Dockerfile is setup this way? Why is the Dockerfile not in the Solution folder instead of the project folder? If you build from the CLI in this way, not only the .sln file is not accessible, but also the .dockerignore and docker-compose files are in the parent folder?

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you include the docker-compose.yml as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of running `docker build` in the project folder, you should run `docker-compose build` in the solution folder. This requires that [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) be installed, however.

Edit: There are lots of cool things you can do with docker compose. For example, you can include all your containers/info in the docker-compose.yml and run `docker-compose up -d`. This will build you images, download any repo images, deploy the containers, and put them into detached mode! ([reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/))